# croppie.js para cambiar foto de producto

Tags: ajax, mysqli, php7

estoy intentando cambiar la foto de los productos cargados previamente en una base de datos usando el croppie.js para poder controlar el tamaño de la misma, pero al hacer es proceso solo me cambia la foto del primer producto independientemente de que seleccione otra foto de producto para cambiar.

En el listado utilizo el siguiente código:

```
if (!isset($foto)){
    echo'
    <img src="upload/sinimages.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block m-auto img-thumbnail" 
 style="width: 80px; height: 80px" alt=""/>';
 } else {
     echo'
    <img src="upload/'.$foto.'" class="img-fluid d-block m-auto img-thumbnail" 
 style="width: 80px; height: 80px" alt=""/>'; 
 }
echo'
</div>
<div><div class="clearfix mb-3"></div>
<div class="file-select">
<input type="file" name="insert_image" id="insert_image" aria-label="Archivo" 
accept="image/*" hidden />
<input type="text" id="date1" value="'. $id .'">
<label for="insert_image" class="label1 d-block m-auto text-center bg-gradient-info" 
style="width: 120px">Subir Foto</label>
</div>';
```

En el input id=data1 le estoy pasando el id del producto y lo puse en type="text" para poder visualizar que el valor que tome sea el correcto del id.

Paso siguiente botón subir Foto, selecciono la foto, se abre un modal en el cual se cropea usando el siguiente scripts

```
 $image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
 enableExif: true,
 viewport: {
  width:200,
  height:200,
  type:'square' //circle
},
boundary:{
  width:300,
  height:300
}    
});

$('#insert_image').on('change', function(){
$date1 = $('#date1').val();
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
  $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
    url: event.target.result
  }).then(function(){
    console.log('jQuery bind complete');
  });
}
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
$('#insertimageModal').modal('show');
});

$('.crop_image').click(function(event){
$image_crop.croppie('result', {
  type: 'canvas',
  size: 'viewport'
}).then(function(response){
  $.ajax({
    url:'vistas/insert.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{
        date1: $date1,
        "image":response
    },
    success:function(data){
      $('#insertimageModal').modal('hide');
    }
  })
  });
  });
```

Luego por medio de Ajax paso la variable data1 al archivo insert.php en donde hago todo el proceso de subir la imagen a una carpeta y tomar su nombre y actualizarlo en la base de datos.

```
include("pdo.php");
    $userID = $_POST['date1'];
    $folderPath = '../upload/';
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $_POST['image']);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $nombre = uniqid() . '.png';
    $file = $folderPath . $nombre;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
    
    $query = "UPDATE productos SET foto = '$nombre' WHERE id = '$userID'";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute())
{
echo 'Image save into database';
//unlink($nombre);

}
    echo json_encode("image uploaded successfully.");
```

Este es el proceso, pero solo logro que me actualice la primer foto del listado de productos. No logro encontrar la lógica de porque lo hace.
Gracias por su atención y posible solución al problema.

Answer (score 0):

Es que en donde solo se actualiza la primera foto de los productos independientemente de cuál selecciones, parece estar relacionado con la forma en que estás manejando el ID del producto (date1) en tu código JavaScript. Como estás utilizando un elemento HTML con el mismo ID (date1) para todos los productos en tu listado, el valor de date1 siempre se refiere al primer producto, lo que provoca que solo se actualice la foto del primer producto en la base de datos.

Para resolver este problema, puedes hacer las siguientes modificaciones en tu código:

En lugar de utilizar un solo campo de texto oculto para almacenar el ID del producto seleccionado, puedes asociar el ID a cada producto de forma individual. Puedes hacer esto utilizando atributos de datos personalizados en tu código HTML.

Asegúrate de que el ID del producto seleccionado se recopile correctamente cuando se haga clic en el botón "Subir Foto" para cada producto. Esto significa que debes vincular el ID del producto seleccionado al elemento #insert_image para cada producto en particular.

Comment: le puse un alert y efectivamente no me toma el valor del value del input id="date1"
siempre me muestra 1, pero la verdad que se muy poco y no se como resolverlo

Comment: nadie me puede dar una ayuda practica de como hacerlo?